Turning black-and-white boxes in a $4\times4$ grid to all-white with two operations
One of my friends and I do maths problems sometimes, but this one has had us stumped and we don't know what to do to solve it.

A magic lock is made of a $4\times 4$ grid. The colour of each box on the grid is either black or white and can be
changed through suitable operations. There are two types of operations one can perform on the lock:

Flip: Change all colours on a particular row or column to the opposite.
Shift: Translate the boxes in a particular row (respectively, column) either left or right (respectively, up or
down) by one unit along its direction. If one translates to the right by one unit, the rightmost box will be
moved to the leftmost, and a similar rule applies to other cases.

The lock will be opened if the colours of all boxes are turned white through a sequence of legal operations.
• Can the lock always be opened regardless of its initial configuration?
◦ If so, explain the reason. If not, can you characterise those initial configurations that can eventually
open the lock?
• Can you construct an algorithm which opens the lock from an arbitrary initial configuration with the
fewest number of shifts? The number of flips is not counted.

We answered the first bit: Any lock with an odd amount of white tiles is impossible. But we couldn't figure out the rest.
I made up some python code (via csinschools.io) for an engine that cycles through them randomly and lets you solve them, but I don't know how to think of an algorithm that solves them for you.
Again just want a new way of looking at it, not the answer (but I might want it eventually). Some help on what to do with the code would be extremely appreciated and sorting out how to make it solve them all itself in the minimum moves.

"but we couldn't figure out the rest. "  What rest?  Question 1 answer: No.  If you start with an odd number of whites it will never unlock.  Question 2 answer: A shift doesn't change the number of colors.  A flip with change a number of of colors in a row from $k$ to $4-k$. This will keep parity so a configuration with odd number of blacks will allways have an odd number of blacks. Question 3 answer: No.  It's impossible to unlock if there are odd number of blacks.  I'd say you are done.

If you four or more blacks shift them until you get all four in a row or colmum and make them all white.  Eventually you'll either have all white or two black.  If you have two black there will be either a row or column with only one black.  Flip it.  You now have four blacks.  shift them untill they are all in the same row or column.  Flip it.

"Additionally, it's also impossible to solve when the number of blacks is 2 mod 4"  I don't think that is true. See my comment above.

Hey thanks for the input but I'm still struggling a bit the link to the code works it just takes a bit to run. I was hoping to get some help making a formula or something to find the minimum amount of moves.

If that's what you hope to get, edwardo, then that's what you should edit into the body of your question, instead of hiding it down here in the comments.

thanks for the suggestion, I added it to the body.

Here is a more structural way to look to the problem.
Let $$F=\Bbb F_2=\Bbb Z/2$$ be the field with two elements, $0$ and $1$, (taken modulo two, if seen as integers,) which replace below the chosen colors black and white (written here in alphabetic order, to have a canonical choice).

A specific grid configuration is thus an element of the vector space
$$
V = F^{4\times 4}=M_{4\times 4}(F)
$$
over the field $F$, consisting of all matrices with $4\times 4$ entries.
It has $2^{16}=65536$ elements.
There is a vector subspace $W$, generated by all eight "flip matrices", which are matrices with either one and only one row filled in with $1$-entries, else zero, called "row flip matrix", or a transpose of such a matrix (so that that row becomes a column), called "column flip matrix".
The dimension of this subspace is $7$, since the eight vectors have one easy relation, the sum of the row flip matrices is equal to the sum of the column flip matrices. It turns out that this is the only linear relation between them.
So the space of configurations of "grids up to flips (but no shifts)" is the quotient space $V/W$. It has dimension $16-7$. Now restrict to the configurations which can be "moved" to the default configuration $0$, the zero matrix. Since all operation preserve the sum of the elements in the grid, and this sum is zero for the configuration $0$ (and for any $w\in W$), we have in fact a space $V_0$ of configurations to consider instead of $V$. This $V_0$ is a vector space of dimension $15$, has $2^{15}$ elements.
But now we consider them modulo flips, modulo $W$, so we land in a quotient space $V_0/W$ with $2^{15-7}=2^8=256$ elements.
These are not too many elements! A quick computer program should be able to analyze the few cases and deliver a quick verdict. Let us go one step further.

We try to find a simple list of representatives for $V_0/W$. Pick some matrix $v\in V_0$. Using column flips (elements of $W$) is possible to make the first row equal to zero. Using row flips for the other three rows we then make the first column equal to zero. This is all we can do with $W$ (with flips), all seven $F$-degrees of freedom are now burned. Let us call this procedure norming.
The remained $3\times 3$-submatrix (with last three rows/columns) is the only freedom we have, and the sum of the entries here must be zero. Pick eight bits among the $3\times 3$ at fixed positions once for all times. The ninth position has to be adjusted by parity, pick it to be on the diagonal (in the corner). These are the possible $2^8=256$ possible grid configurations. The representative may not be optimal for the specific purpose of "seeing" a quick path to $0$, but is a good way to get the
configurations named in a handy manner.

Note now that there is a symmetry of configurations that we may want to use to get a smaller set. For each $v$ observe that the transposed element / matrix $v'$ has the same distance to $0$. (The minimal or not number of moves from $v$ to $0$ is by transposing moves the same as from $v'$ to $0'=0$.)
There are $2^{5}=32$ symmetric representatives, of the shape
0 0 0 0
0 a b c
0 b d e
0 c e a+d    (position with a+d takes care of parity)

(so $a,b,c,d,e$ can be freely chosen).
Among the $2^8$ representatives, there are thus $2^8-2^5=224=2\cdot 112$ configurations that can be seen as $112$ pairs of "similar" grids.

In case of a row or column which has only zero entries in the $3\times 3$ corner, we have further symmetries, that we may want to exploit or not...

We want to build a graph now with the above listed $32+112$ configurations to be solved. We take two such representative configurations, $v_1,v_2$, and join them with an edge if there is a possibility to take some element in $v_1+W$, some element in $v_2+W$ and obtain from one the other one by a shift in the one or the other directions, since these are the moves to be minimized.
Let $S$ be one of these shifts. It is a linear map $S:V\to V$, which induces a map $S:V_0\to V_0$, but it (sometimes) "scrambles" (elements of) $W$. So $v_1+W$ will be directly joined with $v_2+W$ "by $S$" iff we can solve the linear equation:
$$
v_1+w_1 = S(v_2+w_2)\ .
$$
This means $v_1-Sv_2$ is in an $S$-fixed set, in the set of all vectors of the shape $Sw_2-w_1=Sw_2+w_1$. Even better, working in the set of all vectors modulo $W$, it means that $v_1-Sv_2$ modulo $W$ is in $W+SW$ modulo $W$.
The operation we do now is as follows.
Compute once for all times for each $S$ the representatives for $(SW+W)/W$.
Start now with representative matrices $v_1,v_2$, and a possible shift $S$ (well, shifting in first row or column may not be of any use), build $v_1-Sv_2$, take its representative, and check if it is in $(SW+W)/W$. If yes, join with an edge.

Let us also put it conversely, start with $v_2$ modulo $W$. The vector space
$(SW+W)/W$ has dimension $9-7=2$, so it has four elements. The zero quotient vector is useless, but any $w'$ among the other three may be useful. Then take $Sv_2+w'$, represent it modulo $v_1$, (make zeros in first row/column), and join $v_1$ and $v_2$ (with an edge labeled $S$).

The given problem reduces now to a problem of finding the shortest path between two vertices in the graph, one of them being the unlocked vertex $0$.


As wanted, i will stop here after giving some way to attack the problem.


Regarding the code section,
i would use sage, which is python+batteries.
(The code linked is python code, and it was constructing "permutations" / moves, that may be maybe easier to reach using structure.)
The "general field" $F=\Bbb F_2$ with 2 elements is for instance already there as GF(2), and so is also the space of matrices over this field. For instance:
M = MatrixSpace(F, 4, 4)
m1 = M(matrix([[1,1,1,1], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0]]))   
m2 = M(matrix([[0,0,0,0], [1,1,1,1], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0]]))   
m3 = M(matrix([[0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [1,1,1,1], [0,0,0,0]]))   
m4 = M(matrix([[0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [1,1,1,1]]))   
m1t = m1.transpose()
m2t = m2.transpose()
m3t = m3.transpose()
m4t = m4.transpose()
W = M.submodule([m1, m2, m3, m4, m1t, m2t, m3t, m4t])

# Let S be the right shift of the first column.
sm1 = M(matrix([[0,1,1,1], [1,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0]]))   
sm2 = M(matrix([[0,0,0,0], [0,1,1,1], [1,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0]]))   
sm3 = M(matrix([[0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,1,1,1], [1,0,0,0]]))   
sm4 = M(matrix([[1,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,1,1,1]]))   

# Let WW be SW + W, the module obtained by adding to W also its shifts
WW = M.submodule([m1, m2, m3, m4, m1t, m2t, m3t, m4t,
                  sm1, sm2, sm3, sm4])

The sage (iron python) interpreter gives now:
sage: W.dimension()
7
sage: WW.dimension()
9
sage: M.dimension()
16
sage: W.cardinality()
128
sage: M.cardinality()
65536
sage: WW.cardinality()
512

